# Why do I get a NoMethodError with this Ruby module?

Tags: ruby, module, worker

I am programming a distributed system where a worker performs some job and in order to start the worker a `init.rb` is started which loads the `lib` folder and performs some configuration.

#### Structure

```
init.rb
lib
|-- modulename
|   |-- foo.rb
|   |-- configuration.rb
|   `-- worker.rb
`-- modulename.rb
```

#### init.rb

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__))

require "bundler/setup"
require "modulename"

ModuleName.configure do |c|
    c.log       = "module.log"
    c.pool_size = 10
end
```

#### modulename.rb

```
require "sidekiq"

require "modulename/foo"
require "modulename/configuration"
require "modulename/worker"

module ModuleName
    def self.config
        @config ||= Configuration.new
    end

    def self.configure
        yield(config)
    end
end
```

#### worker.rb

```
module ModuleName
    class Worker
        include Sidekiq::Worker

        REDIS_POOL = ConnectionPool.new(:size => ModuleName.config.pool_size, :timeout => 3) { Redis.new }

        def dosomething
            # ...
        end
    end
end
```

If I now run `ruby init.rb` I get a NoMethodError: `<class:Worker>: undefined method config for ModuleName:Module (NoMethodError)`

I don't really understand why, please give me a hint on how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modulename.rb you're requiring worker.rb, so ruby goes off and runs the code in that file, including the bit where you set  `REDIS_POOL`, which tries to call `Modulename.config`

`Modulename.config` hasn't been defined yet (you only do so at the bottom of modulename.rb, hence the error.

You probably only want to create the redis pool lazily, or at the very least after the configuration has been updated.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I took the configuration idea from [Integrity](https://github.com/integrity/integrity) where for example the Sinatra App is required before the code for configuration is run, why does it work there?

Comment: Presumably they don't call .config while the load is being loaded. You'd be fine if instead of that constant you had `def self.redis_pool; ...`

Comment: I looked into the source, they're using references to Integrity.config only inside of method definitions, which I am not, since the redispool constant is defined for a class. `def self.redis_pool;...` seems most reasonable to use!